Google play console is asking for mobile and tablet screenshots while uploading the Tv app
I am developer, I have developed the an android Tv app and I am truing to upload to the play store. In my case I developed the app only for the android, but while store listing they are asking for the mobile and tablet screenshots. But I don't have the screenshots of both device. How to solve this issue, or it is required to upload the mobile and tablet screenshots. if I have done something wrong while creating the app on google play store console.
I don't want to upload the mobile and tablet files

You can simply upload the mobile app screenshot; there’s no need to include both mobile and tablet screenshots.

I design for the Tv screen, If anything wrong i did while creating the app on google play console?

You can post TV screenshots in the Mobile section as well. If you encounter any errors related to resolution or sizes, you can save your application as a draft and submit it later.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic
